# how to set different message on application startup in android?

Tags: android, message, startup

I am creating one application for student. I need to set the different message whenever
user open application.I don't understand how to do this or which method use for this.
I search lot of articles but i didn't found anything.
So please provide me some reference or code.

Comment: You read the about the fundamentals of android, this would guide you on how to do this. You're not going to spout garbage at the user, there will be a pattern.

Comment: any reason for negative vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your messages in a persistent storage. In android, you could use SharedPreference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html, or a Sqlite databse  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html depending on your specific need. Store the messages in either of them and read back a different message each time.
Store some msgs in a SharedPreference at some point in your Activity:

```
SharedPreferences pref =    getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor ed =pref.edit();
        ed.putString("0","msg0");
        ed.putString("1","msg1");
        ed.putString("2","msg2");
        ed.putString("3","msg3");
        ed.commit();
```

Then in onCreate(), retrieve a random sg and diplay to the user:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences pref =    getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Random r = new Random();

        String msg = pref.getString(r.nextInt(4)+"", "none");
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
```

Comment: I have some knowledge about storage but i need method which show message on startup

Answer (score 2):

You can store your messages using any storage like sqlite,file or sharedprefrences and retrive message randomly on app opning..

Comment: If you retrieve message from any storage and display it in toast or dailogBox from onCreate method than it would be displayed to user at the app startup..

Answer (score 1):

You should read the about the fundamentals of android, this would guide you on how to do this. You're not going to spout garbage at the user, there will be a pattern. Once you find the pattern then you turn that logic into java.

Answer (score 0):

Use AlertDialog

Code example below taken from:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

// set title
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

// set dialog message
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click yes to exit!").setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, close
                // current activity
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

// create alert dialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

// show it
alertDialog.show();
```